# How to add a text search functionality on a website which will list all places the searched text is present on all pages and its path

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement where user wants to have a search text bar. Any text searched should list all the places the searched text is present on all the web pages of the website. When user clicks on any of the places, it should directly open that tab or page and highlight the text.
For Example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jr5tK.png)

This should list all the places Name is present on the website and when clicked on any search it should take to the page on which it is present.

I have found some thing related on a chrome extension.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/achjncdillalojkjfjemfmcfcibohpdl

Answer (score 0):

This is a pseudo-program which should get you started. You'll have to write the code yourself. Hope this helps!

```
// Indexing the data
function indexWebsiteContent() {
    // Traverse all pages
    for each page in website {
        let textContent = extractTextFromPage(page);
        let pagePath = getPagePath(page);
        storeInIndex(textContent, pagePath);
    }
}

// Build search Interface
function createSearchInterface() {
    // Add search input and button to the website
    addSearchInputToWebsite();
    addSearchButtonToWebsite();
}

// Handle search requests
function handleSearch(query) {
    let searchResults = searchInIndex(query);
    displaySearchResults(searchResults);
}

// Navigate the search result
function onSearchResultClick(result) {
    let pagePath = result.pagePath;
    navigateToPage(pagePath);
    output(result);
}
```

Comment: Looks good. Will this this approach